# Regex that searches for a starting character, anything in between, then an ending character?

Tags: javascript, regex

So basically, I have a hugeee list of values that I copied from my site and would like them as just plain text. I need to create a regex for Javascript that removes the unwanted stuff

Here is what the values look like before hand:

```
<option value="111122223333">Some text (45)</option>
<option value="345835385390">Some text (10)</option>
<option value="456727235764">Some text (50)</option>
```

Here is what they need to look like afterwards:

```
Some text
Some text
Some text
```

Is this possible with 1 regex, or will many be needed?

My thinking is that a regex looks for `<` anything in between, and then `>` could be used on both the opening and closing `option` tags. Then the regex could be slightly modified to look for opening `(` and then closing `)` to remove the counter numbers to the left of the 'Some text' string.

Still learing regex, so it would be great if someone could also add a small explanation to their answer so that I could have some understanding of it. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to remove this from the source code rather than have JS process it every time the page loads?

Comment: *"Is this possible with 1 regex, or will many be needed?"* : yes

Comment: @j08691 - I created just a small application that is processing this for me so I can simply copy and paste the plain text into a word document that I need.

Comment: @paddy - One, or many? Not very clear since their were two questions in the same sentence, haha.

Comment: Exactly.  You asked two questions covering all possibilities.

Comment: Is the format always the same? In other words, are the last five characters always to be removed?

Comment: @j08691 - The `value` will always have the same amount of digits. The text within the `option` tags will always be different. The counter (inside the parenthesis) is always different. Other than that, yes, the format is always the same.

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NKMtL/?

Comment: Yes actually @j08691, works quite well actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably simplify this if you can use a library like jQuery. In that case you can use the text() method of a jQuery object to get the inner text, then run a simple regex to remove the '(xx)' part:

```
var vals = $('option').map(function() {
   return $(this).text().replace(/\s*\(\d*\)$/, '');
});

// vals => ["some text", "some text", "some text"]
```

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jhummel/U46pH/

if you can't use a library I think you are looking for a regex like:

```
/<[^>]+>([^\(]+)\(\d*\)<[^>]+>/g
```

**edit**

You asked for a regex explanation, let's look at it part by part

- / = start the regex
- < = find a '<' character
- [^>]+ = find any character that is not a '>' one or more times
- > = find a '>' character
- ( = start a group, anything in the parens will be saved for later
- [^(]+ = find any character that is not a '(' one or more times - need to escape it with a backslash because the paren is a reserved character in regex
- ) = close the group
- ( = find a '(' char - need to escape it with a backslash again
- \d* = find any numbers zero or more times
- ) = find a ')' character - escaped again
- < = find a '<' character
- [^>]+ = find any character that is note a '>' one or more times
- > = find a '>' character
- / = end the regex
- g = regex flag. Means find all the matches don't stop after the first match

Comment: Wow, works great! Would prefer to just use the simple regex. Your jsfiddle removes the counter next to the text, although the regex does not. Is there an edit I need to do to make the regex do that aswel?

Comment: Updated the fiddle to show a regex example

Comment: Added an explanation of the reg ex as well.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a ton. Breakdown was very interesting, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

If that's all you hope to accomplish then you can use something like:

(>)(.+)(<)

and then grab the second group out of the match.

EDIT: The parentheses are used to denote groups.

Comment: Why the capture groups on the angle-brackets?